# How to integrated Lombok library and JDeveloper IDE

Tags: jdeveloper, lombok

How do I integrate the Lombok library with the JDeveloper IDE? My JDeveloper's version is 11.1.2.4.0

Answer (score 0):

In JDeveloper 11.1.2.4.0 the easiest would be to integrate Lombok through an Ant Build task :

- Add Lombok jar to jdevelopper library
- Create Ant script  https://projectlombok.org/setup/ant

> ```
> <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build" source="1.8">
>   <classpath location="lib/lombok.jar" />
> </javac>
> ```

- Add Ant Script to JDeveloper ant build : https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/adf/part4-098813.html

> Now you will need to change the build.xml files so that all the path
>   references are correct and refer to the variables defined in
>   build.properties. There are six items that need to be changed in each
>   file (the examples below show the changes for the Model project
>   build.xml file—you should make similar changes to the ViewController
>   one):
>
> The property file path (use a relative reference as described above): 
>   Figure38
>
> The mkdir element of the model.init target (variable name changed): 
>   Figure39
>
> The fileset element of the model.clean target (variable name changed):
>   Figure40
>
> In the model.compile target, change the destdir property of the javac
>   element (variable name changed):  Figure41
>
> In the model.compile target, change the path property of the src
>   element (use the newly defined model.src.dir variable):  Figure42
>
> In the model.copy target, change the copy and fileset elements (change
>   the variable name and use the newly defined variable for src): 
>   Figure43

TL;DR : You can also use maven even if it's not supported by default on this version of jdeveloper.

Comment: Is there a JDeveloper version that is compatible with lombok and maven? Sorry for question, but it's my first time working with jdeveloper.

Comment: JDeveloper is compatible with Ant and Maven starting 11gR2. Lombok can be run inside JDevelopper using Ant or Maven as described in my answer